# Is making kubernetes masters schedulable a really bad idea?

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

It's a cash strapped start-up. What are the worst consequences of running only three nodes, three schedulable masters?

Are there some ways can one mitigate against the risks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/highly-available-master/

> **Best practices for replicating masters for HA clusters**
>
> Try to place master replicas in different zones. During a zone failure, all masters placed inside the zone will fail. To survive zone
>   failure, also place nodes in multiple zones (see multiple-zones for
>   details).
>
> Do not use a cluster with two master replicas. Consensus on a two-replica cluster requires both replicas running when changing
>   persistent state. As a result, both replicas are needed and a failure
>   of any replica turns cluster into majority failure state. A
>   two-replica cluster is thus inferior, in terms of HA, to a single
>   replica cluster.
>
> When you add a master replica, cluster state (etcd) is copied to a new instance. If the cluster is large, it may take a long time to
>   duplicate its state. This operation may be sped up by migrating etcd
>   data directory, as described here (we are considering adding support
>   for etcd data dir migration in future).

I would like to emphasize the following quote

> A
>   two-replica cluster is thus inferior, in terms of HA, to a single
>   replica cluster.

If less then 3 nodes will be used then it is basically more safe to run 1 master, but if one goes down there will be an issue as well. So it is better to run at least three masters.